# How to pass named loop labels to a macro in Rust?

Tags: macros, rust

Using a macro that breaks out of a loop works, but I want to pass in a label to be able to define which outer loop to break out of.

Passing the argument in as an expression gave a syntax error, the only way I managed to get this to work was to pass in a `block` however this isn't very elegant, e.g.:

```
my_macro({ break 'outer; });
```

Is there a way to pass:

```
my_macro('outer);
```

... that can be written in the macro as `break $my_label;` that expands into `break 'outer;` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Passing it as the versatile `tt` (token tree) works:

```
macro_rules! my_break {
    ($label:tt) => { break $label; }
}

fn main() {
    'outer: loop {
        println!("Start of outer");
        loop {
            println!("Start of inner");
            my_break!('outer);
            println!("Not reachable");
        }
        println!("End of outer");
    }
    println!("End of main");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e51f2486377d659b09e76aa3cafcf3f0&version=stable&backtrace=0)

To future readers, there's an [accepted RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1590) adding a lifetime specifier for macro parameters.